# React-native: difference between refresh and restart app

Tags: react-native

I am wondering what's the difference between `Ctrl + R` refresh the app, and double click home button and swipe away the app.

I thought `Ctrl + R` would restart the app, but doesn't look like in a new process. How this `Ctrl + R` works internally then?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + R` in react native tells your app to reload JavaScript code only. It doesn't stop and start a new process.
Double click home button and swipe away the app mean you terminate your app completely.